# I have a problem in navigation between pages when running my app ionic on android device

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

I'm working on an ionic app. it does work correctly on browser but when I try to run it on android device , I have access only to the first page ( because I have added it to  routes in app-routing file with redirection ) but when I click on a button that supposed to navigate to another page it doesn't work and show me page not found [http://localhost/page/pagename] , it's the same problem for all pages. But as I said it works fine on browser.
I'm using this.router.navigate
Thank you

Comment: Please share your app.routing code and how you're doing the router.navigate.